# Combining two 'for' loops - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python, for-loop

For a current project, I am planning to combine the two for loops below so can save the input in one single data table.

My attempts to merge the loops e.g. with `for word, freq, element in ([common_words],[polarity_list]):` have so far led to the following message `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`.

Is there any smart tweak to make this run? The corresponding code is as follows:

```
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = str(get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 150))
    polarity_list = str([TextBlob(i).sentiment.polarity for i in common_words])
    for element in polarity_list:
        print(i, element)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(i, word, freq)
```

Comment: those are not lists, they are strings

Comment: Good point, thanks. I had to convert them to strings as I am otherwise receiving the message `TypeError: The 'text' argument passed to '__init__(text)' must be a string, not <class 'tuple'> `

Answer (score 1):

you can use:  for word, freq in enumerate(common_words):

Comment: Thanks, I tried that - it is yielding the same notification though `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Since `common_words` seems to be a list of tuples, you may need to save each `word` in `polarity_list`:

```
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 150)
    polarity_list = [(word, TextBlob(word).sentiment.polarity) for word,_ in common_words]
    for word, polarity in polarity_list:
        print(i, word, polarity)
```

I think your code as posted had a couple of issues which conspired together to confuse:

```
common_words = str(get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 150))
```

This list here is a list of `tuples`: each item being a word and a number.

Then this line:

```
polarity_list = str([TextBlob(i).sentiment.polarity for i in common_words])
```

does two things wrong: The iteration uses `i` which will overwrite the `i` from the outer loop. Plus the `i` is a `tuple` which I guess `TextBlob` doesn't like.

To fix both issues in one, my code generates `polarity_list` by first discarding an element of the `tuple` like this: `word,_ in common_words` so it can use `word` like this: `TextBlob(word)`.

Comment: That's very helpful, many thanks. I am still getting a notification that the line `polarity_list = [word, TextBlob(word).sentiment.polarity for word,_ in common_words],` is yielding a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Let me however see if I can find a solution here

Comment: Sorry, that should be: `polarity_list = [(word, TextBlob(word).sentiment.polarity) for word,_ in common_words]`

Comment: Thanks, I think we almost got it. I am getting the message `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` now...